# Are there differences between using ref in a match and ampersanding a non-reffed match?

Tags: rust, reference, pattern-matching

Are these two `match` branches equivalent?

```
struct Quux { wibble: u8 }

enum Foo { 
    Bar(Quux),
    Baz(Quux),
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn quux(&self) -> &Quux {
        match self {
            Foo::Bar(ref quux) => quux,
            Foo::Baz(quux) => &quux,
        }
    }
}
```

If so, why does `ref` exist?

Comment: Normally `ref` exists to prevent a _move_ from the matched object into a local variable, and force a borrow instead. So I would expect the second match arm to move the contents of `self` into a local variable `quux`. But that would disallow returning `&quux` from the function, so something else must be going on. Perhaps the match ergonomics feature is inserting a `ref` automatically?

Comment: Note that in your example, `self` is of type `&Foo`. Both match arms result in `quux` being of type `&Quux` – in this particular case, the `ref` is simply inferred in the second arm, since a move is impossible (this is sometimes called "match ergonomics"). Adding an additional ampersand will actually result in an `&&Quux` in the second arm, but the compiler will apply a deref coercion, so this coercec to `&Quux` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do make a difference when we're matching **value** instead of **reference**. Consider the example:

```rust
enum Foo { 
    Bar(i32),
    Baz(i32),
}

fn main() {
    // bar is a value.
    let bar = Foo::Baz(13);

    // Uncomment line below to make bar become a reference.
    //let bar = &bar;
    
    let i = match bar {
        Foo::Bar(ref x) => x,
        Foo::Baz(x) => &x,
    };
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Compiling it gives the error

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:24
   |
13 |     let i = match bar {
   |         - borrow later stored here
14 |         Foo::Bar(ref x) => x,
15 |         Foo::Baz(x) => &x,
   |                        ^-
   |                        ||
   |                        |`x` dropped here while still borrowed
   |                        borrowed value does not live long enough
```

The `x` in `Foo::Baz(x)` arm has taken the ownership of the `i32` inside `Baz`, and being dropped at the end of the arm. That's why `i` cannot borrow `x`, it doesn't live long enough. On the other hand, the `x` in `Foo::Bar(ref x)` arm has no problem, since it is just borrowing the `i32` inside `Bar`.

However, if we uncomment the `let bar = &bar;` line, `bar` will become a reference, and `ref` will be inserted automatically in each arm (according to the [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#binding-modes)). So it compiles.

In your code, since the `quux` borrows `self` (`quux(&self)`) instead of taking ownership (`quux(self)`), that means the `self` in `match self` is a reference, and therefore it compiles.